# error de valor NULL en INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando en una plataforma en PHP y MySql y en el código de insertar datos en una tabla me lanza continuamente "NULL Error en esta consulta :
INSERT INTO....". Tengo varias tablas y el código es igual pero funciona. En este no consigo ver el error. Puedo borrar y editar pero no añadir por el error. Me podéis por favor ayudar? No encuentro el error.
He intentado corregirlo volviendo a escribir el código. Cuando inserto directamente en la base de datos funciona todo correctamente. En la tabla lo tengo puesto de forma que todos los campos pueden ser nulos menos el ID

Este el código

```
<?php
  $page_title = 'Agregar Checklist';
  require_once('includes/load.php');
  // Checkin What level user has permission to view this page
   page_require_level(1);
?>
<?php
$all_checklist = find_all('checklist');
$all_departamentos = find_all('departamento');
$all_delegacion = find_all('delegacion');
$all_superior = find_all('superior');
$all_users = find_all('users');
$all_coches = find_all('coche');
$all_phones = find_all('phone');
$all_informatica = find_all('informatica');
$all_tablets = find_all('tablet');
$all_pantallas = find_all('pantalla');
$all_mediosPago = find_all('mediosPago');
$all_llaves = find_all ('llaves');
?>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_checklist'])){
    $req_fields = array('userName','name',);
    validate_fields($req_fields);

   if(empty($errors)){
     $userName   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['userName']));
     $name   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));
     $superior   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['superior']));
     $adelanto   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['adelanto']));
     $departamento   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['departamento']));
     $delegacion    = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['delegacion']));
     $modeloP = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modeloP']));
     $nTelefono   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nTelefono']));
     $nSerieP = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nSerieP']));
     $fundaP = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['fundaP']));
     $cargadorP   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['cargadorP']));
     $auricularesP = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['auricularesP']));
     $otrosP   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosP']));
     $modeloT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modeloT']));
     $imeiT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['imeiT']));
     $nSerieT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nSerieT']));
     $fundaT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['fundaT']));
     $cargadorT    = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['cargadorT']));
     $sim = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['sim']));
     $otrosT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosT']));
     $hostName = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['hostName']));
     $nSerie = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nSerie']));
     $modelo   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modelo']));
     $cargador = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['cargador']));
     $maletin   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['maletin']));
     $raton   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['raton']));
     $firmaDigital   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['firmaDigital']));
     $otrosInf   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosInf']));
     $modeloPan   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modeloPan']));
     $nSeriePan    = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['nSeriePan']));
     $otrosPan = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosPan']));
     $modeloC   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['modeloC']));
     $matricula = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['matricula']));
     $tarjetaSolred = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['tarjetaSolred']));
     $llaveUno   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llaveUno']));
     $llaveDos = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llaveDos']));
     $botiquin   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['botiquin']));
     $kit   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['kit']));
     $cadenas   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['cadenas']));
     $kilometrosE   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['kilometrosE']));
     $viaT   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['viaT']));
     $otrosCo    = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosCo']));
     $llavesOficina = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llavesOficina']));
     $llaveRac   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llaveRac']));
     $llaveCaja = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llaveCaja']));
     $llaveCajaF = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['llaveCajaF']));
     $mando = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['mando']));
     $otrosLlave   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosLlave']));
     $visa = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['visa']));
     $otrosVisa   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['otrosVisa']));
    
    $date    = make_date();
     $query  = "INSERT INTO checklist (";
     $query .=" userName,name, superior, adelanto, departamento, delegacion, modeloP, nTelefono, nSerieP, fundaP, cargadorP,auricularesP, otrosP,modeloT,imeiT,nSerieT,fundaT,cargadorT,sim,otrosT,hostName,nSerie,modelo,cargador,maletin,raton,firmaDigital, otrosInf,modeloPan,nSeriePan,otrosPan, modeloC, matricula,tarjetaSolred,";
     $query .=" llaveUno, llaveDos, botiquin, kit,cadenas, kilometrosE,viaT,otrosCo, llavesOficina,llaveRac,llaveCaja,llaveCajaF,mando, otrosLlave, visa,otrosVisa, date";
     $query .=") VALUES (";
     $query .=" '{$userName}','{$name}','{$superior}', '{$adelanto}','{$departamento}','{$delegacion}','{$modeloP}','{$nTelefono}','{$nSerieP}','{$fundaP}', '{$cargadorP}','{$auricularesP}', '{$otrosP}','{$modeloT}','{$delegacion}','{$modeloP}','{$imeiT}','{$nSerieT}','{$fundaT}',";
     $query .="  '{$cargadorT}','{$sim}', '{$otrosT}','{$hostName}','{$nSerie}','{$modelo}','{$cargador}','{$maletin}','{$raton}', '{$cargadorP}','{$firmaDigital}', '{$otrosInf}','{$modeloPan}','{$nSeriePan}','{$otrosPan}','{$modeloC}','{$matricula}','{$tarjetaSolred}',";
     $query .="  '{$llaveUno}','{$llaveDos}', '{$botiquin}','{$kit}','{$cadenas}','{$kilometrosE}','{$viaT}','{$otrosCo}','{$llavesOficina}', '{$llaveRac}','{$llaveCaja}', '{$llaveCajaF}','{$mando}','{$otrosLlave}','{$visa}','{$otrosVisa}','{$date}'";
     $query .=")";
  var_dump($sql);
    
     if($db->query($query)){
       $session->msg('s',"Producto agregado exitosamente. ");
       redirect('add_checklist.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Lo sientimos pero el registro falló.');
       redirect('product_1.php', false);
     }

   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('add_checklist.php',false);
   }

 }

?>
```

Comment: Ya he encontrado el error, no estaba declarando bien dos variable. Corregido y funcionando. Gracias!!!!